# Dynamically create tables based on the total counts of another table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to be able to create tables based on the total rows in another table.

Let's say I've a table A, and the count is 500K, and so I wanna be able to create 5 tables each of 100K dynamically inside a procedure in oracle.

table A will have counts changing each time, but I would still want to be able to create tables with 100K max, for instance, tomorrow the table A has 550K, I want to be able to create 6 tables with 5 tables having 100k and last one with 50k.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    ttl_tables NUMBER;
    var_loop NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(COUNT(*)/(500000) AS INT) INTO ttl_tables FROM 
    px_extract_checks;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ttl_tables); 

    LOOP
    var_loop := var_loop + 1;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (' || CREATE TABLE ' || 'table' || var_loop || ' ' || 
(Card_Number) || ');
    EXIT WHEN var_loop = ttl_tables;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Something like above.

Comment: **Why** would you want to do that?

Comment: what is the driver for not keeping the records in the same table? When do you expect the rows to migrate to new tables? How would anyone know what table to look for?

Comment: Partitioning or Materialized Views might be the option you should use.

Comment: Also related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57470650/create-table-inside-procedure Please be advised: You will create yourself a lot of trouble if you carry on with a design like this.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you. Could you please elaborate how is this particular design a problem? I am newbie to SQL world, and I really have no clue how this design is problematic. I would really appreciate you response. :)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Also, I do not have much idea about how I can use materialized view here? Don't know much about partitioning either.

Comment: What is the purpose of your program? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Partitioning is part of Enterprise Edition. Is that what you have? By the way, why would `COUNT(*)/950000` not be an integer? And if it’s so important to cast it to one, why do you save it in a `NUMBER` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a small block to help you out using dynamic queries.

You need to use actual column names and little bit changes in the following code as per your requirement:

See inline comments for more information on steps.

```
BEGIN
    -- BEFORE CREATING THE TABLES, NEED TO DROP THE TABLES
    FOR T IN (
        SELECT
            TABLE_NAME
        FROM
            USER_TABLES
        WHERE
            TABLE_NAME LIKE 'MY_TABLES_DYNAMIC%'
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || T.TABLE_NAME;
    END LOOP;

    -- CREATING THE TABLES USING TABLE_A
    FOR I IN (
        SELECT
            CEIL(COUNT(1) / 100000) AS CNT -- DIVIDED THE COUNT OF ROWS BY 100K
        FROM
            TABLE_A
    ) LOOP
        -- USING CTAS
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE MY_TABLES_DYNAMIC_'
                          || I.CNT
                          || ' AS '
                          || ' SELECT COL1, COL2, ... FROM'
                          || ' (SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, ...., ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.PRIMARY_KEY_OF_TABLE_A) RN '
                          || ' FROM TABLE_A A)'
                          || ' WHERE RN BETWEEN '
                          || ( ( I.CNT - 1 ) * 100000 ) + 1
                          || ' AND '
                          || ( I.CNT * 100000 );
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you Tejash. I wrote some thing similar but I know where I might be going wrong. I am going to take help from your code, and update if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this below code will help you for your requirement, you can test it by changing the column names,table names and counts accordingly:

```
declare

tname_count number:=0;

t_name varchar2(500);

begin

select count(1) into t_count from A;

for  k in 1.. t_count 
loop

  if mod(k,100000)=0 then
    tname_count:=tname_count+1;

    t_name:='TAB_'||tname_count;

  execute immediate 'create table '|| t_name||' (id varchar2(50))';

  end if;

    end loop;

  if floor(t_count/100000)<>0 then 

    tname_count:=tname_count+1;

     t_name:='TAB_'||tname_count;

    execute immediate 'create table '|| t_name||' (id varchar2(50))';

    end if;

  end;
```